# Vuex is only removing the first element

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have the following setup, trying to remove the `activeNote` from the `notes` array using `DELETE_NOTE` mutation. But it only removes the first element of the array.

the mutations.js is:

```
export const mutations = {
  DELETE_NOTE (state) {
    console.log(state.activeNote) // here the activeNote is the correctly selected note
    if (typeof state.notes !== 'undefined' && state.notes.length > 0) {
      state.notes.splice(state.activeNote, 1) // here no matter what the first element is removed
      if (state.notes.length === 0) {
        state.activeNote.text = ''
        state.activeNote.favorite = false
      } else {
        state.activeNote = state.notes[state.notes.length - 1]
      }
    }
  },
  SET_ACTIVE_NOTE (state, note) {
    state.activeNote = note
  }
}
```

the actions.js is:

```
export const actions = {
  deleteNote: ({ commit }) => commit('DELETE_NOTE'),
  updateActiveNote: ({ commit }, note) => commit('SET_ACTIVE_NOTE', note),
}
```

the getters are:

```
const getters = {
  activeNote: state => state.activeNote,
  notes: state => state.notes,
}
```

the component I call the mutation from is:

```
<template>
  <div id="toolbar">
    <i @click="deleteNote" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'toolbar',
  computed: mapGetters([
    'activeNote'
  ]),
  methods: mapActions([
    'deleteNote',
  ])
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) incorrectly. The first argument of splice is the *index* to start changing the array. Instead of

```
state.notes.splice(state.activeNote, 1)
```

you should use

```
state.notes.splice(state.notes.indexOf(state.activeNote), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue.